# How to make ctags to defaulty index?

Tags: ctags

I have recently started working on multiple projects. All projects are in completely C language. I have installed exuberant-ctags for easy browsing of code. ctags is a wonderful tool but I have a problem. I generally clone many repositories and browse code for my day to day development. So is there a way by which ctags automatically generates tag file without me manually creating a tag file whwnever I download a new repo and also when I add new code to the existing repo?

Comment: How are you 'downloading a new repo'?  Hooking into that mechanism will greatly depend on the tool you are using.  (ie are you downloading a tarball, or cloning a git repo, or...)